# Use OOPS to design database tables schema?

Tags: database, oop, database-design, architecture

Usually, we firstly check the project requirements and set up tables, and then do 1/2/3-NF normalisation.

I don't like this way, because it is not Object-oriented way. So any body could share exprience how we use OOP to design complicate table schema/relationship ?

Even a link/book ISBN is welcome. That is very important for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Relational databases can't be object oriented.  Trying force them into an object-oriented model has been the cause of many poor designs over the years.

The core of object oriented programming is putting the code and the data into the same "object".  Putting code into a relational database is a bad design.  Make your relational database good at storing normalized data (the 1/2/3-NF you talked about).

You can do your application design first (please do), and that will influence what tables are created, and how much you normalize them, but the database design itself should not be object oriented.

Comment: OOP has 2 basic ideas: Code and data are combined in a single object; and objects can inherit from other objects. You can't do either of these things with a relational database. I suppose you could consider sprocs to be "code in a database", but they're not tied to an object. Triggers are arguably code attached to an object, but they're a very special case. It's like asking how to make your television fry chicken. That's not what a tv is for. Presumably someone could create a database product that has code attached to each table, but what would be the advantage of this?

Comment: Instead of doing the application design first (some horrible databases come from this.) determine how you are going to use the data once it is in the database first.  Look at reporting, data extracts, and processes that use the data first. Look at legal requirements and auditing requirements and data that you need to meet those needs that the user may not need to see. NEVER design using Object oriented principles because that defeats the purpose of using a relational database. Design first for data integrity, second for performance and third for data security.